# Error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++

Esta función en **C++** me está generando un 'error':

> segmentation fault (core dumped).

Estoy tratando de programar la codificación de *Shannon*, he hecho dos test con ficheros **.txt** distintos, uno lo ejecuta perfectamente obteniendo el resultado deseado, pero al testear el segundo fichero esta función me genera el error mencionado.
l = limite izquierdo
r = limite derecho

```
struct node {
    char sym; //caracteres
    float pro; //probabilidad 
    string codigo="";
};
```

```
void shannonF(int l, int r, node *p){ 
    if(l==r){ 
        return; 
    }
    else if(r-l == 1){
        p[l].codigo= p[l].codigo + "1";
        p[r].codigo= p[r].codigo + "0";
    }
    else{
        float sumaT=0, sumaP=p[l].pro, sumaMitad;
        int i,z;
        // suma de probs en intervalo especifico
        for (i=l; i<=r; i++){
            sumaT += p[i].pro;
        }
        sumaMitad = sumaT * 0.5f;
        //asignamos  0 o 1 dependiendo en que intervalo se encuentra
        for (i=l; i<=r;) {
            p[i].codigo= p[i].codigo + "1";
            i++;
            sumaP += p[i].pro;
            if (sumaP > sumaMitad) break;
        }
        for (z=i; z<=r ;z++) {
            p[z].codigo= p[z].codigo + "0";
        }

    shannonF(l, i-1, p);
    shannonF(i, r, p);
  }
};
```

Tengo entendido que puede ser un problema con los índices., inicialmente `l=0` y `r = (p.size)-1` donde `p` = numero de nodos.

Actualización:
luego de depurar con gdb obtuve lo siguiente:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

> 0x00007ffff7abb670 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Comment: Ese tipo de problema sucede cuando intentas leer una posición de memoria que no te corresponde. Puede ser al intentar desreferenciar un puntero o acceder a un elemento de un arreglo. ¿Podrías debugear el código y ver dónde y bajo que condiciones ocurre? Sería de ayuda para responderte.

Comment: esta función es recursiva. Para entender el fallo son necesarias las condiciones iniciales, es decir, qué es `p`, qué valores tiene y cuáles son los valores iniciales de `l`y de `r`. En cualquier caso lo ideal sería que aprendieses a depurar el programa ya que eso te permitiría encontrar el fallo pro ti mismo

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir la definición de `node`?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, lo agregue a la estructura.

Comment: @Mateo, estoy compilando este programa en una maquina virtual, tiene algo que ver?.

Comment: @eferion, hay agregue un poco mas de detalle, estoy intentado depurar con gdb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primer punto, por favor, tabula bien el código porque si no es bastante complicado seguir el código

En segundo lugar, es preferible usar nombres de variables que tengan algún sentido. No hay demasiado problema en usar `i` como iterador en los bucles, pero `p`, `r`, `l` ... esos nombres no aportan nada de información.

Tratando ahora tu problema, si atendemos al caso inicial:

- `l == 0`
- `r == size(p) - 1`

Y revisamos este bucle:

```
for (i=l; i<=r;) {
    p[i].codigo= p[i].codigo + "1";
    i++;
    sumaP += p[i].pro;
    if (sumaP > sumaMitad) break;
}
```

Podemos encontrar un posible punto de fallo:

```
for (i=l; i<=r;) {
    p[i].codigo= p[i].codigo + "1";
    i++;
    sumaP += p[i].pro; // <<--- AQUI
    if (sumaP > sumaMitad) break;
}
```

La explicación es sencilla: Si `i==r` al comenzar el bucle, al hacer `i++` tenemos que `i==r+1==size(p)`. Este valor no se corresponde con un índice válido, por lo que estarás leyendo una posición de memoria que no pertenece al array.

En cualquier caso, es muy raro que este acceso que te comento pueda provocar la señal de SIGSEV.

Para una respuesta más completa sería necesario que expusieses un ejemplo mínimo y completo que reproduzca el problema